# Mass creation of data in Django

Tags: django

I have a model Unit.

```
class Unit(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    max_occupants = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    floor = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    rooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    is_disabled_access = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    balcony_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    recomended_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

Each Unit has all property/s defined in Property table

```
class Property1(CommonInfo):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    is_true = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    propertytype = models.ForeignKey(Propertytype, related_name='propertytype')
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    followup_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Is there a way to mass create all the property to all the units with some default value?

Comment: Django has a `fixtures` feature. Use that

Comment: You need to clarify your question. When you say 'units' do you mean the actual unit model that is being generated as a foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for test code, do it with **factory boy**'s `RelatedFactory`.  See [here](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#reverse-dependencies-reverse-foreignkey).  *Avoid fixtures*.

If this is a once-off task you need to do on pre-existing data, write a **data migration**.  See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

If this is something you want to happen automatically whenever a `Unit` is created, do it using a **post_save signal** handler.  See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save).